# Django Project Multi-Database Config in settings.py

Tags: python, django, configuration, multi-database

I am currently in the process of taking an asp.NET internal website written in C# and redoing it in the Django web framework.  After identifying all of the current data sources being used by the .NET site, I have begun configuring and testing my ability to connect to those databases from within the Django framework.

- **Platform:**  Archlinux
- **Django Version:**  1.3.1
- **Python Version:**  2.7

**Problem:**
Whenever I try to connect to any database that is not defined as the default database, I am unable to do so.  Furthermore, any database that I am unable to connect to, is only when it is defined as **not being** the default.

To further illustrate this point, I will provide redacted examples:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'mssql': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'DATABASE_ODBC_DSN': 'name_of_sql_server',
        'DATABASE_NAME': 'Logs',
        'DATABASE_USER': r'user_name',
        'DATABASE_PASSWORD': 'password',
        'DATABASE_OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'sql_server_driver',
            'dsn': 'MSSQL_Logs',
        },
    }
}
```

If I comment out the first default database definition, and change the name of the mssql database to default, I am able to access the dbshell via:

```
manage.py dbshell
```

However, if I try to directly access the mssql database as it is defined above via:

```
manage.py dbshell mssql
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: handle() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)
```

It is almost as though it is unable to parse the definition properly.  So my question is basically this:  Am I defining the databases incorrectly when pairing them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dbshell, you should use `python dbshell --database mssql`.